# Can it be plot only on one candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I display the plot with the code I wrote, it looks like a picture.

[image]

But I would like to modify the code so that the plot is only displayed on one candle.

[image]

I need help.

```
TP = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + min_profit)

var bool TP_reached = 0

if ta.crossover(high, TP)
    TP_reached := 1
  
close_condition = TP_reached ? TP : 0

plot(close_condition, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=6, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plot(close_condition and not close_condition[1], style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=6, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, 0))
```